# How can I take a users input as a hit or stay to determine to run my function again or to pass it

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The user gets asked if they want to hit or stay. If they hit then I need to run the function again as long as there total score is less than 50. If they go over 50 or hit stay then I need to skip the function. I am assuming this would be done using a while loop but I cannot get a while loop to work. **

```
import random
random.seed(1)

#----------------------                                          #introduction
print("Let's Play Avoid 50!")
print("====Beginning of Round====")
print("Player 1's turn")
#----------------------                                          #dice value and first roll

def game_play(value1, value2):

    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0
    if value1 != value2 and value1 % 2 == 0 and value2 % 2 == 0:
        if value1 > value2:
            player1 = player1 + value1
        else: 
            player1 = player1+ value2
    elif value1 == value2:
            player1 = value1 + value2
    else:
        if value1 < value2:
            player1 = player1 + value1 
        else:
            player1 = player1 + value1
    print("The score for this roll is",player1)
    return player1




dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)

dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)

print("You roll a", dice1,"and",dice2)

game_play(dice1,dice2)

print("Your current total for this round is",game_play(dice1,dice2))
print("Do you want to hit or stay(h or s)?") #need user input here

#while input = hit, run program again while user enters hit or score is less than 50
```

Comment: Your code says "if doubles, player1 gets the sum of the dice. Otherwise, if both dice are even, player1 gets the larger.  Otherwise player1 gets the smaller".  Is that the spec?  You should not be assigning player1/player2 in this function.  You should have a single function that translates "dice" to "score".  Then, you can apply it to player1 in a loop, and then player2 in a loop.

Comment: By the way, by calling `random.seed`, you will play the same game every time.  You almost certainly want to remove that.

Comment: You can visualize the loop, right?  `def play_player1` will set score to 0.  Then, in a while loop, say "Your score is X.  Hit or stay?"  If they stay, you return with the current score.  Otherwise, you roll the dice, translate the dice, add it to the score, and loop.

Comment: Thank you, how can I get the function to loop back if player 1 wants to hit. I tried 'print("Your current total for this round is",game_play(dice1,dice2))
print("Do you want to hit or stay(h or s)?") #need user input here
play_again = input()
while play_again == h:
    game_play(dice1,dice2)' but get an error or my other attempt I would just take an input and could not get the while loop to run

Comment: and yes, here is the rules the program needs to be able to execute: Player 1 rolls 2 dice. If the 2 dice match, they get the sum of the dice (e.g. if they roll two 4s they get 8 points). Otherwise if both dice are even (and don't match), they get the maximum of the 2 dice (e.g. if they role a 4 and a 2, they get 4 points). Otherwise they get the minimum of the 2 dice (e.g. if they role a 5 and a 2, they get 2 points).

Comment: Player 1 is asked if they want to "hit" or "stay" ("hit" means roll again, "stay" means stop rolling). If they want to hit, they roll 2 more dice and get more points as described in the previous step.

Keep repeating Step 2 until Player 1 says they want to "stay" (stop rolling).

Comment: I'm going to post the pseudo-code as an answer, because there's no good way to format it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's rough pseudo-code for how you could go about this.

```
def get_score(value1, value2):
    if value1 == value2:
        return value1 + value2
    if value1 % 2 == 0 and value2 & 2 == 0:
        return max(value1,value2)
    return min(value1,value2)

def player1_turn(score=0):
    while 1:
        print( f"Your score is {score}.  Hit or stay?" )
        ...accept input...
        if stay:
            return score
        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print( f"You rolled {dice1} and {dice2}." )
        score += get_score(dice1,dice2)
```

You will, I presume, have a similar function for a computer player.  Then you have a main loop that might look something like:

```
while player1 < 50 and player2 < 50:
     player1 = player1_turn(player1)
     print( f"Player 1 has {player1} points" )
     player2 = player2_turn(player2)
```

That's a rough idea.  You'll have to fill in the details.